# Controller annotations angular-dart

Tags: annotations, dart, angular-dart

In the angular dart documentation it says best practice is to declare your controllers using controller annotations.  But I get an error when trying to do that stating that annotations must be a constant variable.  Digging into the source I can see that there is no controller annotation in angular dart 1.0

From `package:angular/core/annotation.dart`

```
export "package:angular/core/annotation_src.dart" show
    AttachAware,
    DetachAware,
    ShadowRootAware,

    Formatter,
    DirectiveBinder,
    DirectiveBinderFn,

    Directive,
    Component,
    Decorator,
    Visibility,

    DirectiveAnnotation,
    NgAttr,
    NgCallback,
    NgOneWay,
    NgOneWayOneTime,
    NgTwoWay;
```

Has the controller annotation been depreciated?  If so, what is the best practice for instantiating a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller were removed in Angular.dart 1.0.

There is a `rootContext` which is a controller initialized at application startup, otherwise use a component instead of a controller.

See for an example

- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/example/web/todo.dart#L116
- https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/commit/e6a0f7747e7f890f35cb1201ef65eaf080fcfc5c

Comment: Can you please help me understand better how this should work in practice?  For instance chapter 2 in the angular dart tutorial has me creating a controller using the controller annotation, then I use ng-repeat and access information in the controller.  Since that is no longer how it works, what is the proper way to do it?  I tried to just change the syntax from `@controller` to `@component` but there is no publish as property anymore either so I don't know how to access properties on the component.  Also aren't components more like directives than controllers?

Comment: You should be able to just reference fields from the component without a prefix. I didn't check in detail but I think this is the tutorials already  ported to Dart 1.0 https://github.com/vicb/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/1013-v1/Chapter_06/lib/component